# How to use keras.utils.Sequence with multiple files

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am looking at the documentation and this guide

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence

https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly

And I need to write in

```
    def __len__(self):
```

and

```
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
```

Which gets the length of the dataset, and the getting a data sample using a particular index. So I am wondering if this is appropriate to use for multiple files, and if so, are there any best practices for this?